# MySQL Query to replace string with value

Tags: mysql, select

I have requirement like as below.
Need a MYSQL query to replace value with maching the below condition.
i have a table containg the Product ID

```
Product_ID
1
2
3
4
5
15
25
```

I want to replace the 5 with value of 1.111. My requiremnet is this that it should only replace the 5 value not the 15 value.
example 5 should be 1.111 but it sould not replace the 15 value.

Comment: What's the problem? Just update the row `WHERE product_id = 5`. Why would that affect 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IF()` or `CASE` to select a different value when the value meets a condition.

```
SELECT IF(product_id = '5', '1.111', product_id)
FROM yourTable
```

or

```
SELECT CASE product_id
        WHEN '5' THEN '1.111'
        ELSE product_id
       END
FROM yourTable
```

`CASE` generalizes more easily to other values that you want to replace, since you can have multiple `WHEN` clauses.